# correct template method to wrap a ostream

Tags: c++, ostream

Given a class

```
class ostreamWrapper
{
    private:
        ostream * str;

    public:
        ostreamWrapper operator << (const char *);
}
```

where `ostream * str` will point to std::cout and `ostreamWrapper operator << (const char *)` sends the given text to the wrapped ostream `str`.

In this case, I can only `instance << "const char * text"` and no other printable data. Unlike directly `<<`ing a std::cout or std::cerr.

How can the operator method be implemented so it accepts any type of data just as std::cout or std::cerr directly do?

Comment: Provide a constructor that initializes the pointer to the stream object.

Comment: The `operator<<` return a `ostreamWrapper` object, when you write. `ostreamWrap << "a" << "b" << "c";` the first call to the operator would return the wrapper that would be used in the second call, and so on. For other types of data you could make template as `template <typename T> ostreamWrapper& operator<<(const T& t) { if (str) *str << T; return *this; }`, see the return type (reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, write a public `operator<<` template so it can accept any type and simply forward it to the wrapped `ostream`.

```
template <class T>
ostreamWrapper& operator<<(T&& x) {
    *str << std::forward<T>(x);
    return *this;
}
```

Second, in order to accept insertion of stream manipulator templates such as `std::endl`, add a second public `operator<<` that specifically accepts manipulators intended for the wrapped `ostream`:

```
ostreamWrapper& operator<<(ostream& (*manip)(ostream&)) {
    *str << manip;
    return *this;
}
```

Omitting the second overload will cause insertion of overloaded manipulators or manipulator templates to fail with "ambiguous overload" or similar error messages.

Comment: Or even better, just provide a stream buffer that does the actual manipulation and wrap a stream around that. Or use Boost.IOStreams.

Comment: This works, but I cannot understand why the second operator<< is necessary. Why is it that the generic T&&x doesn't cover the manipulators?

Comment: @PedroLM the manipulators such as `std::endl` are function templates, so if you try to pass them to a `T&&` arg, deduction fails, i.e., the compiler can't figure out which specialization of `std::endl` you want.

Answer (score 2):

See an example of the proposed implementation, it would deduce the template parameter type and print accordingly, if you could use C++11 see @Brian answer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ostreamWrapper {
private:
    ostream* str;

public:
    ostreamWrapper(ostream* str_v) : str(str_v) {}

    template <typename T>
    ostreamWrapper& operator<<(const T& t) {
        if (str)
            *str << t;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    ostreamWrapper osw(&std::cout);
    osw << 1 << " texto " << std::string(" otro texto ") << 1.2345;
    return 0;
}
```