# How to avoid creating file if no data sent to std::ofstream?

Tags: c++, std

When C++ creates `std::ofstream` it instantly and implicitly creates the underlying file.

I am totally fine with this behaviour unless I have a code which only during its run can see if any data at all will be produced.

So, I want to avoid creating empty files when no data sent to them (kind of transactional integrity: no data, no changes on file system).

I see two approaches I don't like much:

1. See if something was sent to the stream (`tellg()`) and remove the file if the stream was empty. I don't like to create and delete files (sometimes there are many of them) and `remove` operation itself puts too much responsibility.
2. Create `std::stringstream`, collect output there and create `std::ofstream` and copy content only in case the stringstream is not empty. Much better, but still requires temporary memory allocation which could be big.

Is there a better solution for this? Am I missing some idea?

In form of code:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("file.txt");

    // Some code that might or might not output to ofs
    // Some other code that might or might not output to ofs
    // Some more code that might or might not output to ofs

    // It would be nice if file is not created if no data sent to ofs
}
```

So, the code could contain many places where the output will be performed.

Comment: Don't open the file until you actually have to write to it?

Comment: Perhaps wrap all output to the file with a class, which overload the `<<` operator and checks if the file is open each time the operator function is called, and if not open then open the file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, first one this will lead to many checks in the code, since writing could occur in many places or the "reporting" code. The second one sounds good, let me try this in code. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating the `std::ofstream` object with a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) that takes a filename, opens the file. You can work around this by only providing the filename via `open` when you actually need to write.

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs;

    // determine whether you need to write

    if (/*need_to_output*/) {
        ofs.open("file.txt");
    }

    // write to ofs
}
```

to avoid checking whether the file is opened or not, consider this simple wrapper class

```
class lazy_open_ofstream {
public:
    explicit lazy_open_ofstream(std::string filename) : _filename(std::move(filename)) {}

    lazy_open_ofstream& operator<<(auto other) {
        if (!ofs.is_open()) {
            ofs.open(_filename);
        }
        ofs << other;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::ofstream ofs;
    std::string _filename;
};
```

Then use is as

```
lazy_open_ofstream ofs("file.txt");

// write to ofs or not
```

*Note*: you might want to adjust the `operator<<` to your needs.

Comment: This will lead to many checks in the code, since writing could occur in many places or the "reporting" code. It works, but having many such "if"s won't make code better. Updated  the code and comment in question. Thank you, anyway. I missed this way.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I updated the answer with a simple wrapper class will take care of all testing

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Let me wait till tomorrow (according to SO recommendations) for possible better answer and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Why not use [`ofs.is_open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, good catch. On the other hand one could reason on performance. Kidding in this context, of course.

Comment: Two questions on the constructor: (1) What is the reason it is `explicit`? What kind if implicit conversions do you expect and suppress here? (2) Why to use std::move on std::string? Shouldn't it handle the content movement on its own?

Comment: @DamirTenishev (1) string should never be implicitly converted to `lazy_open_ofstream` thus its a good idea to add explicit. (2) it is needed to move the string [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929800/is-stdmove-really-needed-on-initialization-list-of-constructor-for-heavy-membe).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude edited the question to use `is_open()`

Comment: What kind of overload should be done to make it working with `std::endl`? Current implementation doesn't compile `ofs << std::endl`; Here is the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T9foejv4z). Would this [implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/8odTYKTfW) with 'manip' handling be correct?

Comment: @DamirTenishev yes this is correct, you need both overloads. [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615253/correct-template-method-to-wrap-a-ostream)